# How to set different store for different comboboxes in one column?

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid, store

I have grid with to columns. In second column i have to comboboxes (for example at 1st row and 3rd). How to set different store for them?
Values of second combobox depends on first combobox

[here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Efz5.jpg)

I saw one example but there was different columns, not rows

Comment: why do you need 2 separate stores for this? Your backend should be able to filter the data for 2nd combo based on 1st combos value, which you should pass as a parameter when loading 2nd combo.

Comment: Can you point out some references to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has not been tested but will give you an idea. use the cellediting plugin "beforeedit" event handler to get combo1 value and load combo2.

//beforeedit eventhandler for combo2. fired before cellEditing is triggered.

```
beforeedit:function(editor_, e_){
  //get combo1 record, then get combo1 value
  var rec= this.grid.store.getAt(rowIndexForCombo1);
  var cbo1Val = rec.data.COMBO_1;

  var cbo2 = e_.column.field || e_.column.editor;
  //pass combo 1 value to combo2 proxy as extraParam, then load combo2.
  cbo2.store.proxy.extraParams = {COMBO1VAL:cbo1Val};
  cbo2.store.load();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can filter your store , when the combobox get fucus.

listeners : {

```
focus : function(...){

        store.clearFilter();
        store.filterBy(function(item){
            return .....;//true or false;
        });
}
```

}